# Showing pop up message to show the error message when the code stops running WXPYTHON

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new in wxpython. Is there any way to show pop up message to show the error message when the code stops running? So the user doesn't need to look at the terminal to see that actually the code stops.

Thanks!

Comment: `sys.excepthook` can be set to handle uncaught exceptions and e.g. show a dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to illustrate the comment from @Michael Butscher and the answer from @Dan A.S.

You can use `sys` and `traceback` to catch and display the event in a `wx.MessageDialog`

```
import wx
import sys, traceback

def my_message(exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback):
    msg = "Oh no! An error has occurred.\n\n"
    tb= traceback.format_exception(exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback)
    for i in tb:
        msg += i
    dlg=wx.MessageDialog(None, msg, str(exception_type), wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()

sys.excepthook = my_message

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", size=(360,100)):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, size)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKey)
        self.Show()

    def OnKey(self, event):
        print ("alpha" + 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None,title="Press a key")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wxPython dialogs? I think this is the easiest way to display an alert message.

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
wx.MessageBox('Your error message', 'Your error title', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
```

More info:

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.MessageDialog.html

https://pythonspot.com/wxpython-dialogs/